# Solr Join - getting data from different index

Tags: join, solr, lucene

I'm working on a project where we have 2 million products and have 50 clients with different pricing scheme. Indexing 2M X 50 records is not an option at the moment. I have looked at solr join and cannot get it to work the way i want it too. I know it's like a self join so I'm kinda skeptical it would work but here it is anyway.

here is the sample schema

core0 - product 
core1 - client

So given a client id, i wanted to display all bags manufactured by Samsonite sorted by lowest price.

If there's a better way of approaching this, I'm open to redesigning exciting schema.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I don't understand your use case.  How is a client related to a product in this case?  The way it sounds to me, I'd say forget the client id, and perform a search something like: q="manufacturer:Samsonite" sort="price asc"

Comment: clients have to log in to search a product, so for bag X which normally sells for $10, client A's price can be $9, client B can be $9.50. i can not just search using default price as this will have an effect in scenario where search is sorted by lowest/highest price

Answer (score 1):

Solr is not a relational database. You should give a look at the [sharding](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DistributedSearch) feature and split your indexes. Also, you could write your custom plugins to elaborate the price data based on client's id/name/whatever at index time (**BAD** you'll still get a product replicated for each client).

How we do (so you can get an example):

- clients are handled by sqlite
- products are stored in solr with their "base" price
- each client has a "pricing rule" applied via custom query handler when they interrogate the db (it's just a value modifier)